# CubeMX code generation

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I have a cubeMx code generation problem. I generated the whole project with cubeMX but after some modifications I got the following compiler error:

> warning: cannot find entry symbol Reset_Handler; defaulting to
>   08000000

I figured out that the source of the error is first line of my .cproject file.

Before (compiler => OK):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

After(compiler => error!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still a bug in CubeMX but I found a better more reliable solution to the problem. Navigate to Properties menu / Paths and Symbols / Source Location. Instead of adding the whole project library as a source location with no filter, add every folder one by one (with the add folder button). In this case CubeMX won't fail when generating source locations. My .cpoject file looks like this:

```
<sourceEntries>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH" kind="sourcePath" name="Common"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH" kind="sourcePath" name="Display"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="sourcePath" name="Drivers"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="sourcePath" name="Inc"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="sourcePath" name="Middlewares"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="sourcePath" name="Src"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH" kind="sourcePath" name="Tasks"/>
        <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH" kind="sourcePath" name="font"/>    
</sourceEntries>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset_Handler is defined in an assembly language file that is generated by CubeMx:

Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32Fxxx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32fxxx.s 
  (xxx depending on your board type)

You should make sure this is being built as part of your project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, see my solution below!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile it turns out that this is a bug in cubeMX version 4.14.0.
There is a walkaround until it is fixed.

**SOLUTION**

revert the sourceEntries to this in **.cproject** file

```
<sourceEntries>
    <entry flags="VALUE_WORKSPACE_PATH|RESOLVED" kind="sourcePath" name=""/>
</sourceEntries>
```

See more details here:

- [Official ST forum](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Java/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=https%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Est%2Ecom%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2FSTM32Java%2Fcubemx%20code%20generation%20issue&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D758000F9A0E3A95BA69146A17C2E80209ADC21&currentviews=105)
- [OpenSTM32 forum](http://www.openstm32.org/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?forumId=7&comments_parentId=2490#threadId7)

**UPDATE**

**Better solution found see above! (accepted answer)**

Good luck,
Dave